# Tensor of tensored categories

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

Given two $V$-categories $C$ and $D$ tensored over a symmetric monoidal category $V$, could I form the "tensor" of $C$ and $D$?

More precisely, is there a $V$-category $T(C,D)$ such that $V$-functors $F : C \otimes D \to E$ which preserve tensors in each component (i.e. $F(K \otimes C,D) \cong K \otimes F(C,D) \cong F(C, K \otimes D)$, where $K$ is a $V$ object) are in one to one correspondence with $V$-functors $T(C,D) \to E$? What are the conditions on $V$ for such category to exist?

I'm also interested in the case that $V = \mathsf{Set}$, and tensor is copower. I am also interested in the case that copower is replaced by some form of colimit.

Comment: What does $K$ stand for? Also, you seem to assume that $V$ is *symmetric* monoidal.

Comment: This is discussed in Deligne's paper in the *Grothendieck Festtschrift* (for the linear case, at least)

Comment: @Berci $K$ is a $V$ object that is tensoring (copowering). And yes, it seems that $V$ should be symmetric. I reflected this in the question, thanks.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez the one entitled "Catégories Tannakiennes"? By linear do you mean an Ab-enriched categories?

Comment: @gluglu: Probably, the article is quite famous. Have you found an answer to the question?